# Rails: carrierwave uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, initialization

I have Rails 3

Carrierwave 0.5.4

//app/uploaders/fasta_uploader.rb

```
class FastaUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
      'public/data/01_fasta'
  end
end
```

//migration

```
class AddFileUpToCvits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :cvits, :fasta, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :cvits, :fasta
  end
end
```

//app/models/cvit.rb

```
class Cvit < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :fasta
    mount_uploader :fasta, FastaUploader
end
```

//form

```
<%= form_for(@cvit, :html => {:multipart => true, :onsubmit => "return ray.ajax()" }) do |f| %>
  ...
  ...
  <%= f.file_field :fasta %><br></br>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get this error: uninitialized constant Cvit::FastaUploader

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A simple reset of the server fixed the problem -_- You live and you learn.

Comment: The server reset is necessary if you have not restarted since generating your first uploader. I believe it's because your first uploader class results in a new 'uploaders' folder being created, and it is not on the search path by default.

Comment: I made it too, and you save me any real time in solving it.

Comment: Ha, struggled for a while with this - the old "off and on again" sorted it, cheers dude!

Comment: On my Mac, I had to close the terminal session and restart rails console.  A simple stop and restart in the same terminal session didn't work for me.

Comment: @Feckmore thats suprising, I am pretty sure 3 years ago when I did this I was working on a Mac.

Comment: And if you use spring with rails, make sure to `spring stop` as well.

Comment: got me too... doh!. Even 4 years later.

Comment: I had numbers in the name of my upload file, once I changed it to all letters it worked.

Comment: I heard there was a restart server fixing problems party here. got me too... doh!

Comment: got me too... doh! But well I'm already the 53rd guy upvoting this answer. And the first from 2016.

Comment: got me too... doh!

Comment: got me too... doh!
(isn't it amazing how many "issues" can be solved by restarting the Rails server and how easy it is to forget do do it?)

Comment: got me too... doh!

Comment: for me i had to clear redis cache and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server doesn't work for me. I restarted my mac and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem was with some initialization code before the uploader could be initialized itself.

I had a reference to one of my models that had a reference to the uploader inside of an initialization file located at config/initializers.